# CSS - Change BackgroundColor Based on child color

Tags: css, reactjs

I Want to change background color based on child element in HEX

example:

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
    <span>
        <h3 style={{ color: item.color }}>Item Color</h3>
    </span>
      ...
 }
```

i have tried `mixBlendMode` (`mix-blend-mode`) but this does the reverse of what I am asking,

So if the `h3` color is white, and the `span` backgroundColor is white, i want to change it to black, and the reverse for black, if color=black then background is white

is there any offical `CSS` way to do this?
and if there any alternative (using JS to detect color from HEX)

`if color=white then bgColor=black`

`if color=black then bgColor=white`

(and so for other colors)

Comment: If the problem is only color invert, you may find this lib useful https://github.com/onury/invert-color

Comment: worked perfectly

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback. If you don't mind - please share your code, so others with a similar problem will have an easier reference to work with

Comment: `<span><h3 style={{ padding: 10, background: invert("#" +  item.code), color: "#" + item.code }}>Color Code: #{item.code}</h3></span>`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way of doing this, but here's a solution I came up with:

First add a ref tag to the element you want to watch:

```
<h3 ref={"tag"} style={{ color: item.color }}>Item Color</h3
```

Than use lifecycle methods to keep track of the color and set that in state in React:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let taggedColor = window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.tag);
    this.setState({
      taggedColor: taggedColor.color
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    let taggedColor = window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.tag);
    if (taggedColor.color !== this.state.taggedColor) {
      this.setState({
        taggedColor: taggedColor.color
      });
    }
  }
```

getComputedStyle converts the HEX to RGB, so now in your span use a conditional based on the RGB :

```
<span
        style={
          this.state.taggedColor === "rgb(17, 17, 17)"
            ? { backgroundColor: "#fff" }
            : { backgroundColor: "#111" }
        }
        className="App"
      >
         <h3 ref={"tag"} style={{ color: item.color }}>Item Color</h3
      </span>
```

Again I'm sure there's an easier way of doing it but this is what I came up with.